# private ip addresses in public DNS servers

Tags: domain-name-system, scripting

I'm looking for a DNS service provider that allow me to:

1. Add LAN IP addresses as A record. For example I need to add 192-168-0-1.example.com mapped to 192.168.0.1. I've tried godaddy and cloudflare. They both don't allow me to do it.
2. Add a script or add through an API that maps x-x-x-x.example.com to x.x.x.x

Does anyone know any service providers that satisfies my requirements?

Comment: Do you own `mydomain.com` and have NS records set at their service? How exactly have you tried to add the A record? What exactly was the error message?

Comment: I own mydomain.com. What I need is a script that maps x-x-x-x.mydomain.com to x.x.x.x so I don't have to add thousands of records.

Comment: You need to find a service provider that has an API for adding domain names and implement script for that API. Alternatively you can run your own name servers and generate zone files. However, it seems that something in your setup is not well thought, since you need such domain names in the first place.

Comment: Found someone who did what I wanted here http://xip.io  However, since I need to use may own domain name, I can't use this guy's service. Apart from building our own DNS server, are there any current DNS providers offer this feature?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want a DNS service for your local area network.  Many routers will not support this but some do.  Those based on DD-WRT or OpenWRT should allow you to add local entries.

It is incorrect to reply with a private network address to a query originating from the internet.

Possible solutions are `dnsmasq` or `bind` running on a Linux server.  Configure the router to use this for DNS lookups.  If you are already running `bind` you can use split DNS to provide different answers to the Internet from those provided the local area network.

The simple solution is to add a `hosts` file entry to any devices that need to connect by domain.  This works for both Linux and Windows although the files are located in different directories.

Comment: What I need is a script that maps x-x-x-x.mydomain.com to x.x.x.x so I don't have to add thousands of records. We can't control the router the users have. It has to be done on a DNS server

Comment: @TeroKilkanen It appears you need to publish your Internet address and have your border router forward to your server.  What you think you want is unlikely to do what you think it will.

Answer (score 0):

I own domains at [Namecheap](https://namecheap.com) and [Gandi](https://gandi.net) and their nameservers do allow such records. Both of them have APIs which could be used to update records, though I'm not sure if they would allow you to create 65536 records to map the full 192.168.0.0/16 address space. (And Namecheap's API is subject to restrictions, like having an account balance of at least $50 or owning 20 domains etc.)

However, I don't understand what are you trying to accomplish here. Do you recognize that these domains will then point to different servers for people not on the same LAN?

Comment: What I need is a script that maps x-x-x-x.mydomain.com to x.x.x.x so I don't have to add thousands of records. I need to use domain names in LAN instead of IP addresses for HTTPS based connections.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly I have used private IPs like 10.10.10.10 and 192.168.1.1 for records on AWS route53.

Hope this helps.